# Results Missing From Google Maps Search

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hello I'm trying find all markers of a certain branch of shops in and area. I'm using this search string to find all shops with the keyword "coral" near to the given location. However it does not find all the shop's markers.

This is my search string:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.5136,-0.1365&radius=5000&keyword=coral

This is the shop's official branch locator:
http://www.coral.co.uk/coral-connect/shop-locator?postCode=WC2H

The official shop locator returns 9 or 10 results in the area but my search string only returns about 7 of those results.

And searching the word "coral" in that area on google maps also gives the same thing

Google Maps Search:
[image: google maps search]

Official Store Locator:
[image: official store locator]

How can I get all the results that the official store locator has in my own app?

Answer (score 0):

The only definitive way to do this would be to ask Coral for a feed from their store locator. Scraping the data from their site is likely to break terms of use.

There is likely to always be a disconnect between Coral's list and any third party list such as Google, Yellow Pages or Royal Mail.

Bear in mind that even Coral's store locator may be out of sync with actual stores, sometimes when a new store is opened/closed the change isn't applied to a website straight away. Also occasionally mistakes are made and markers end up in not quite the right place.